# Apache2 mod_deflate not working

Tags: apache2, gzip, passenger, deflate

Google Page Speed and YSlow says that compression isn't enabled.

Here's my config:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName episodecalendar.com
        ServerAlias www.episodecalendar.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/episodecalendar.com/production/current/public/
        <Directory /var/www/episodecalendar.com/production/current/public>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/www/episodecalendar.com/production/current/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog /var/www/episodecalendar.com/production/current/access.log combined
        ServerSignature On

        #Gzip/deflate
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/javascript text/css application/x-javascript
        BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
        BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
        BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

        DeflateFilterNote Input instream
        DeflateFilterNote Output outstream
        DeflateFilterNote Ratio ratio

        LogFormat '"%r" %{outstream}n/%{instream}n (%{ratio}n%%)' deflate
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/deflate_log deflate
</VirtualHost>
```

Have I missed something?

mod_deflate IS enabled, and the header says:

```
Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate
```

and the actual log looks like this:

```
"GET /stylesheets/application_packaged.css?1292696861 HTTP/1.1" 6927/31722 (21%)
"GET /stylesheets/print.css?1292696853 HTTP/1.1" 323/625 (51%)
"GET /javascripts/application_packaged.js?1292696861 HTTP/1.1" 25146/74582 (33%)
```

PS. I run Rails with mod-Passenger

Comment: `Accept-Encoding` is a client header, no?

Comment: Testing http://www.episodecalendar.com/ with Page Speed and YSlow tells me that compression is enabled. `GET /stylesheets/print.css?1292696853 HTTP/1.1`, `Host: www.episodecalendar.com` gives
`HTTP/1.1 200 OK`, `Content-Encoding: gzip`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry my bad. I'm behind a proxy server at the office, so by the time it hits my computer, the request is already unpacked.